# Ramda: replace NULL values in json array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

We have a json array that has the form:

```
[
{id: 123, name: 'abc', symbol: 'xyz'},
{id: 456, name: 'def', symbol: null},
...
]
```

We are looking for a Ramda transformation that will replace all instances where the 'symbol' property is NULL, with a simple '' (empty string). Any ideas about how this can be done without getting into a forEach or for...next loop?

Comment: The answer from @Tomalak captures exactly what you need.  But the general "without getting into a forEach or for...next loop" can generally be answered pretty straightforwardly.  Here, what would you want to do in your loop?  You want to transform each value into one without a `null` symbol.  Boom!  `map`.  If instead you said, I want to find only those..., you know you'll likely want to `filter`.  If you wanted to find the first one that matches, then `find`.  If you want to combine them all into a single smooshed object, then `reduce`.  That will cover a great majority of your looping needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {id: 123, name: 'abc', symbol: 'xyz'},
  {id: 456, name: 'def', symbol: null},
  // ...
];

const newData = R.map(R.over(R.lensProp('symbol'), R.defaultTo('')), data);

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Marking this as correct answer since it seems the most complete from a "functional" perspective. As well it allows me to hit other individual properties without having to address others I'm not concerned with. However the answers from 김재원 and mac also worked - thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @Gatmando You can always define something like `const defaultPropTo = (prop, def) => R.over(R.lensProp(prop), R.defaultTo(def))` and then simply `R.map(defaultPropTo('symbol', ''), data)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
R.map(({ symbol, ...otherProps }) => ({ ...otherProps, symbol: symbol || '' }))(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lensProp` with `set`.

```
arr.map(o => R.set(R.lensProp('symbol'), o.symbol || '', o))
```